# How to set height of "number-parent" class div equal to "active-lg" class div without JS

Tags: html, css

**Problem** :- How to set height of div with "**number-parent**" class, equal to div with "**active-lg**" class without JS only using css(donot want to set px height)

I have created a JSFiddle,
**Link** :-
http://jsfiddle.net/thakv1/s4v6tLne/

In case the Link is Not accessible,
**HTML** :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Accordion Number Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "active-lg">
    <div class = "header">
        <div class = "number-parent">
            <div class = "number">1</div>
        </div>
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
  <div class = "body">
        <div>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** :-

```
.header{
  border : 1px solid red;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.body{
  border : 1px solid green;
  height: 260px ;
  margin-left: 40px
}
.number-parent{
  display : inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -42px;

}
.number{
  width : 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align : center;
  background-color:red;
}
h3{
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set position for outer most div, in your case active-lg:

```
.active-lg{
    position: relative;
}
```

and then you can use height in % for your .number-parent

```
.number-parent {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -42px;
  height:100%;
}
```

[Here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2rc9zaLj/)

Comment: yes it is working.thanks.Is there any another way where i can apply css only to number-parent and number class div

Comment: not really because when you give height in % you have to set the parent element. Without a parent element your div will be 100% of the page, not the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `height: inherit;` More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_inherit.asp)
:)